# Visual Studio: Stuck on "Adding toolbox items from assembly" for 11 hours

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Uninstalled and then reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 last night, but after installing and updating, once I opened the software it said:

`Adding toolbox items from assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\SDK's\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.dll'."`

So I left it for a few hours and went and got some dinner, came back and it was still going. So I left it on while I went to sleep and then when I woke up it's still doing this.

I tried renaming the DLL but it then started throwing errors on startup and wouldn't open, so I repaired it and am now getting the same error again.

Comment: You are really patient :}

Comment: I provided an accepted answer to this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141070/visual-studio-getting-hang-on-adding-toolbox-items-from-assembly-opening-forms-i/49141357#49141357