# Visual Studio getting hang on Adding toolbox items from assembly opening forms in design mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, acumatica

When I open any web page in design mode, Visual Studio is getting hang on below dialogbox. "*Adding toolbox items from assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehavioursXamlSDKManaged\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.dll*"

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 with latest updated version 15.6.27428.1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Duplicate of this question which has no answer:

[Visual Studio: Stuck on "Adding toolbox items from assembly" for 11 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739115/visual-studio-stuck-on-adding-toolbox-items-from-assembly-for-11-hours)

I would suggest trying to reset the toolbox items if you haven't done it.

To do so open the toolbox from the view menu:
[image]

Then right click in the toolbox and either go into 'Choose Items...' and click the reset button or use the menu option to reset. Going into choose item might give you more insight as to what is going on:
[image]

If that doesn't work you can also try to reset your visual studio settings with this shell command:

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Last resort you could run the visual studio installer from 'Add or remove programs' windows dialog and choose the repair option.